# Enable TLS 1.2 on JDK7 Client side

Tags: java, java-7

According to [Oracle](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/java_8_will_use_tls),

> Support for TLS 1.2 first appeared in JDK 7 (2011). For compatibility reasons, it is enabled by default on server sockets but disabled on clients.

Is there a  way to enable it on the client side as well?

Comment: client side of _what_? what are you trying to do?

Comment: "...sockets but disabled on **clients**." <-- That client.

Comment: For `HttpsURLConnection` (that is, `URL.openConnection` on `https:`) [you can use sysprop `https.protocols`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Customization). Otherwise it depends on what classes or libraries you are using to make the connection; add to your question (with the edit button).